# How to append this span if the LI element is parent AND has UL (children or submenu)

Tags: jquery

I basically want to add arrow if the mousehover my navigation. But two rules should apply:

1. It has to be the TOP parent (I already resolve that in the code)
2. It has to have CHILD elements (UL) submenu, etc. (Which is the problem!)

I can not, no matter what I do get it to only show after conditional if to check if it has children first. Now both links which contaain children, and which not show the arrow.. Please help me.

My code:

```
$("#menu ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$("#menu li").hover(function(){
    if (($(this).parent().attr("id") == 'menu')) {
    $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
    }
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideToggle(500);
},function(){
    if ($(this).parent().attr("id") == 'menu') {
    $('.arrow').remove();
    }
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

Problem: how to add && conditional if to this.parent().attr("id") == 'menu which checks if the LI has children/sub UL

I tried $(this).next().is('ul') no luck! It still append all items with children, and without.

Need your input on this please.

Comment: Do you have `id="menu"` on more than one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't need the `if()` statement. Just make it a requirement in the selector that the `li` is a child of `#menu`.

I assume that the `#menu` element is the top `<ul>` and your `.hide()` was to hide the sub-level `<ul>` elements.

Without seeing your HTML, I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but give it a try:

```
$("#menu > li:has(ul)").hover(function(){
    $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>')
           .find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideToggle(500);
},function(){
    $(this).children('.arrow').remove()
           .end().find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

So this will only fire the hover if the `<li>` is a [direct child](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) of `#menu`, and if it [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) a descendant `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to check for the whether the parent of the `li` element is `#menu` in the hover event handler, then you might as well only select the direct descendent of `#menu` with the direct descendent selector `>`.

Assuming that the `ul` sub-menu element is a child of the `#menu > li` elements (since `ul` elements in another `ul` element is invalid HTML), this code should work:

```
$("#menu > li").hover(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.children('ul').length) {
        $this.append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
    }

    $this.find('ul:first').hide().slideToggle(500);
},function(){
    $('.arrow').remove();
    $(this).find('ul:first').hide();
});
```

This code also uses the `hide()` function instead of the slightly more messy `css('display', 'none'`

Answer (score 0):

`if($(this).parent("#id")) { ... }` should work since parent() only looks at immediate parents.

`if($(this).parent("#id").children("ul")) { ... }` will work when the parent's id is found AND it has an immediate child `<ul />`

Another way to do this is:

```
function doToggle(element){
    element.children('ul').css({visibility:"visible", display:"none"}).slideToggle(500);
}
function doHide(element){
    element.children('ul').css({visibility:"hidden"});
}
$("#menu li").hover(function(){
    doToggle($(this));
},
function(){
    doHide($(this));
});
$("#menu > li").hover(function(){
    $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
},
function(){
    $('.arrow').remove();
});
```

This way, you don't need to traverse the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you bind the hover event to `#menu > li` instead you wouldn't have to check for it being a direct child (i.e. a top level item). Then go ahead and simply query for the second condition:

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function() {
    if ( !$(this).find('ul').length ) return;

    $(this).append('<span class="arrow"></span>');
    ....
}, function() {
    // Just try to remove it, jQuery won't operate on empty sets anyways
    $('span.arrow', this).remove();
    ...
});
```

Here you go.